# How do you load an existing S3 bucket in Sagemaker using R Programming?

Tags: r, amazon-sagemaker

I know how to use python to load an existing s3 bucket in sage maker using R. Something like this:

```
role = get_execution_role()
region = boto3.Session().region_name
bucket='existing S3 Bucket' 
data_key = 'Data file in the existing s3 bucket'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
```

How can one recreate this using R in Sage maker? All i see in the available documentation is how to create a new bucket but none of it mentions how to use an existing S3 bucket. Help would be appreciated.

link to documentation for R in sage maker:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-r-with-amazon-sage maker/

Comment: you are not typing the link correctly: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-r-with-amazon-sagemaker/

Comment: I do not know the details but you can conceptually load `reticulate` library and hopefully execute the same Python code in R.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using Amazon SageMaker!

You can use [SageMaker Session](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/session.html) helper methods for [listing](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/session.html#sagemaker.session.Session.list_s3_files) and [reading](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/session.html#sagemaker.session.Session.read_s3_file) files from S3. Please checkout this sample notebook if you need examples for using SageMaker Session [using_r_with_amazon_sagemaker.ipynb](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/r_kernel/using_r_with_amazon_sagemaker.ipynb) .

Thanks,

Neelam

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sagemaker Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/s3.html#sagemaker.s3.S3Downloader) via reticulate, for example:

```r
library(reticulate)
sagemaker <- import("sagemaker")

uri <- "s3://my-bucket/my-prefix"
files <- sagemaker$s3$S3Downloader$list(uri)
csv <- sagemaker$s3$S3Downloader$read_file(files[1])
df <- read.csv(text=csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use packages from the [cloudyr](https://cloudyr.github.io/) project:

```r
library(aws.s3)
library(aws.ec2metadata) # will mutate environment to add credentials
library(readr)

df <- s3read_using(FUN = read_csv, bucket = "my-bucket", object = "my-key.csv")
```